# Для чего при создании проекта в WebStorm нужно указывать адрес сервера?

Tags: javascript, ide, gulp, jetbrains, webstorm

Проект был начат в sublime и собирается при помощи gulp. Одним из плагинов был browser-sync, который выступает в роли сервера и обновляет файлы на клиенте при их изменении. Так вот потом я решил пересесть на WebStorm и при создании проекта из существующих файлов указал лишь адрес сервера. Теперь когда я нажимаю сохранить файл, сборщик, который так же как и раньше был запущен из консоли, стал зависать примерно на минуту. Почему? Что такого мог WebStorm сотворить за кулисами, что все испортил?

Comment: В таких случаях просто открываю нужную дир (Open), а не создаю проект. После индексации, если все ок, доступны все фишки Grunt или Gulp из WS. Удалите скрытую папку  `idea` из проекта и попробуйте так.

Answer (score 1):

Встроенный веб-сервер Webstorm создан для подобных browser-sync целей, однако для его работы нужно устаналивать плагин в браузера. Самым простым решением будет отключить сервер в настройках, либо отказаться от него при создании проекта.

Comment: А как его правильно отключить? Я залез в настроики проекта и просто удалил путь до моего сайта. Но работа все равно остается медленной. И ещё что интересно, gulp я запускаю вообще отдельно от WS, но при сохранении файла в консоли пишется что сборка началась и на этом зависает на минуту. Я вот что подумал, у ноды, на которой написан gulp, есть побочный эффект синхронных функций. То есть если вклинится в поток с синхронным методом, то он остановить выполнение всего кода. Может так и получается, что gulp только начнет, а затем ws что-то у себя включает и останавливает нафиг все? ЧТо мне делать?

Comment: Если WS и виноват, то все должно вылечиться переустановкой нода)

Comment: @vas причем тут ws? Гулп сам следит за изменением файлов, после изменения запускает сборку, тут редактор вообще никак не влияет